# Find a contiguous sub-array that adds up to a target number and prints out the sub array using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

What would be a divide-and-conquer algorithm to check if there’s a subarray say `A[i : j]` of A such that `A[i] + . . . + A[j] = target value`. What would be a good way to go about designing an algorithm like this that would print out the indices of the sub-array?

The elements in the array are signed, i.e. both positive and negative values are allowed.

Comment: Keep a running total, if the total is too small add the next right element, if the total is too big drop the most left element, if the total matches the target then done.  If the elements and/or target value can be positive or negative, then need a different approach.

Comment: @IDm What makes you think that divide-and-conquer  is the way to go?

Comment: @4386427 The issue is that im trying to get it faster than O(n^2) so by doing a brute force as Eljay described would give me a O(n^3) which I am trying to avoid as it will take too long. so divide and conquer I felt would be the best approach

Comment: @IDm  Eljay approach is linear for positive array elements

Comment: Eljay provides a solution in O(n). is it not a brute force approach.

Comment: They are signed

Comment: @4386427 they are signed

Comment: @Jarod42 they are signed, so they contain negative numbers aswell

Comment: @IDm I edited your question to add that information. Next time: Instead of writing it in a comment, edit the question :-)

Comment: @4386427 youre a superstar thank you. please let me know if there are any other things I need to clear up

Comment: @IDm I don't know an algo that can make this better than O(n^2) (which is easy to achieve). Maybe by calculating and storing intermediate results, it can be done. But... how big arrays are we talking about? And how much memory are you willing to pay for improved performance?

Comment: Calculate cumulative sums for array, sort them, then look for needed difference with two-pointer algorithm described by @Eljay. Complexity is `O(nlogn)`

Comment: @4386427 These arrays can have up to 100,000. how would you go about getting it to do O(n^2)?

Comment: @MBo: But care with "inverted" indexes.

Comment: @MBo I could try that. calclating the cumulitive sums

Comment: @IDm O(n^2) is simply achieved by just calculating all sub-array, i.e. [0:N], [1:N], [2:N], .... During calculation, you always check if target was hitted. That will give a maximum of N*(N-1)/2 loops, i.e. O(n^2). It's just two nested for-loops.

Comment: It's a fine question – but as no real code involved, possibly not suited for this site? Maybe rather [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Aconcagua AFAIK questions about sw algorithms are in-scope for SO as long as the problem is clearly stated.

Comment: @Prune That might be exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. thank you :)